# CircleCI ./gradlew: Permission denied

Tags: android, gradle, circleci, gradlew

I have a `Github` repository, which is builded on `CircleCI`. I get following error:

> export TERM="dumb" if [ -e ./gradlew ]; then ./gradlew
>   dependencies;else gradle dependencies;fi bash: line 2: ./gradlew:
>   Permission denied
>
> export TERM="dumb" if [ -e ./gradlew ]; then ./gradlew
>   dependencies;else gradle dependencies;fi  returned exit code 126
>
> Action failed: gradle dependencies

I can't get what is this caused by, because I give necessary permissions in `circle.yml` file.

```
test:
  override:
    - echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter tools,platform-tools,build-tools-21.1.2,android-21,extra-google-m2repository,extra-google-google_play_services,extra-android-support
    - chmod 777 gradlew
    - chmod a+x gradlew
    - ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/android-sdk-linux ./gradlew dependencies
    - ./gradlew testVanillaDebugUnitTest -PdisablePreDex
    - echo "y" | sudo /opt/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud beta test android run --app app/build/outputs/apk/app-vanilla-debug.apk --test app/build/outputs/apk/app-vanilla-debug-androidTest.apk --device-ids Nexus5 --os-version-ids 22 --locales en --orientations portrait
```

Comment: Anyway you can link to repository and the Circle CI build?

Comment: @mkobit : Yes: https://circleci.com/gh/plaidshirtakos/Trivia-test/5 and https://github.com/plaidshirtakos/Trivia-test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at you `circle.yml` (found [here](https://github.com/plaidshirtakos/Trivia-test/blob/b9dd42bcb4359cf37ae8036fa20e70425db66a52/circle.yml)), the failure is not from lines #25 or #26, it's line #14.

Please notice that order of execution is

1. dependencies:pre
2. dependencies:post
3. test:override
4. test:post

So what you need to do is remove lines 23, 24 and add `chmod +x gradlew` as the first command in `dependencies:pre`

Comment: It helped in this, but there is another Gradle error, which I can't solve: `./gradlew assembleVanillaDebug assembleVanillaDebugAndroidTest -PdisablePreDex returned exit code 1`

Comment: @plaidshirt I'd highly suggest you accept this answer and post a new question with this error. Will be way easier to help you fix this. 

Answer (score 4):

- run: chmod +x gradlew
- run: ./gradlew assemble

So, first set permission, then run the command you want